# How to install the Monaco font?

Tags: fonts

Monaco is the default font in the iTerm terminal for Mac OS X. How can I install it on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 38):

Github user `cstrap` has [a repository](https://github.com/cstrap/monaco-font) with a simple install script that will download and install the font.

Just run the command

```
curl -kL https://raw.github.com/cstrap/monaco-font/master/install-font-ubuntu.sh | bash
```

Comment: And why should we trust this script?

Comment: @moose, I understand what you meant but it came off a bit snarky. We may be able to trust this script because we can view it ourselves and decide if it is safe.

Comment: @KevinHerrera: I think a solution that does not need reading (and understanding!) a bash script from a non-official source is always better. That's what I wanted to express.

Comment: This is why I dislike ubuntu, because people giving irresponsible actions like this. You need to write actual solution in the comments not just have reference to someone's script in the web.

Comment: I do agree with @holms, that's why I upvoted greuze solution, nevertheless this script could be added as an alternative, but the best answer is the one that also explains you how to do it, and the risks involved in sudoing stuff from the internet, of course...

Comment: People, the script is hardly 10 lines of brain-dead easy bash. You probably shouldn't use Ubuntu/Linux unless you are willing to make a small effort for some less important things (like a random font). So yes, read the script and then decide whether to trust/run it or not. You can get it with `wget https://raw.github.com/cstrap/monaco-font/master/install-font-ubuntu.sh`.

Answer (score 29):

1. Download it from http://www.gringod.com/wp-upload/software/Fonts/Monaco_Linux.ttf
2. Double click on the file. A font manager opens.
3. Click on "Install Font"

Comment: Actually, you only need to move the downloaded file to `~/.fonts/`, and command `sudo fc-cache -fv` from the Bash command line, in order to rebuild the font cache. (No font manager opened when I clicked the downloaded file, but I'm using Xubuntu, which might account for that.)

Answer (score 10):

I installed the Monaco font in Ubuntu 16.04 by doing:

1. Download it from https://github.com/hbin/top-programming-fonts/raw/master/Monaco-Linux.ttf
2. Copy the downloaded font into `~/.fonts/`
3. Run `sudo fc-cache -fv`

Comment: no need to run mysterious scripts from the web, just two simple commands...

Comment: As system-wide fonts are stored under /usr/share/fonts, symmetrically the XDG-standard directory to place user fonts is: ~/.local/share/fonts (you just replace /usr with ~/.local)

Comment: sudo fc-cache -fv ~/.fonts worked.