# How to uninstall Monaco font?

Tags: command-line, fonts

I installed Monaco font like [it was described in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/333409/148451) but now I want to uninstall it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script in that answer just downloads the font, moves it into the system's font directory and updates the cache. The relevant commands here are

`sudo mv Monaco_Linux.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom/`

and

`sudo fc-cache -f -v`

In order to remove the font, just delete it:

`sudo rm /usr/share/fonts/truetype/custom/Monaco_Linux.ttf`

If the font is not gone after a restart of the program you're using, force a complete rebuild of the font cache:

`sudo fc-cache -r -v`

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I hit the idea to see the script content after I posted the question. Accepting this answer soon. :-)