# How can I install a pdf font?

Tags: fonts, pdf, texlive, matplotlib, ghostscript

I am trying to save a matplotlib plot as a pdf page as shown in [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) example. Everything is fine until tex fonts are used. That is, I can display plots that use tex fonts, but not save them as a pdf. The error trace (shown below) indicates that I am lacking the font called `cmr12`.

I am running under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have checked that `dvipng` and `gs` are installed (and are at the latest version) and the directory where their executables appear is in `$PATH`. The packages `texlive-fonts-recommended` and `texlive-latex-extra` are installed as well, all as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37218925/2725810) advice. How do I install the missing font(s)?

**EDIT**:

- After not succeeding to install `cmr12.ttx`through the font viewer (see the reply of George and my comment there), I just copied it into `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/lyx` (where `cmr10.ttx` already resided) and updated the cache as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/386034/111162). I also cleaned `~/.cache/matplotlib/` and `~/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache`. However, the error persists.
- I noticed that the file in the trace does not have the `.ttf` extension... I also noticed that there are files `cmr12.pfb` and `cmr12.pfm` in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm`. I tried copying these files into the directory from which the python script is run under the name `cmr12`, but that was not liked...

Here is the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 45, in <module>
    d['ModDate'] = datetime.datetime.today()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2435, in __exit__
    self.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2442, in close
    self._file.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 547, in close
    self.writeFonts()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 647, in writeFonts
    realpath, stat_key = get_realpath_and_stat(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 1038, in __call__
    stat = os.stat(realpath)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/meir/Dropbox/temp/cmr12'
```

Comment: Are you still having this problem? Is the package `fonts-cmu` installed?

Answer (score 0):

To install:

1. Get that font [here](http://www.filewatcher.com/m/cmr12.ttf.26484-0.html),
2. After download right click and select open with `font viewer`
3. Click install
4. Now run this: `fc-cache -fv` to build your font cache files

Comment: When I clicked on install, it changed to "Install Failed". I downloaded from another mirror, opened in font viewer and the font shows as installed. However, I get the same error trace.

Comment: Please see the edit in the post as well.